# How to use an object method with Hash::map()?

Tags: php, cakephp, hashmap, cakephp-2.0

How can i scope the function in `Hash::map()`?

Example:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all');
$results = Hash::map($users, '{n}', 'foo');
```

Where `foo` should be called as `$this->foo`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do so by passing an array where the first entry points to the object, and the second one holds the method name: `array($this, 'foo')`

```
Hash::map($users, '{n}', array($this, 'foo'));
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php